# Anyone know how I would send form data without page refresh?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form sending chat messages to database and a php file getting them on a page as styled elements I use ajax to get messages from my php file and display them every 2 seconds.

The only problem is that when the form is submitted, it refreshes the page.
Which is quite annoying.

Anyone know how I could get data to the database without the page refreshing?

Comment: Depends how you're submitting the form to send the data. Is it submitted via ajax or submitted to the action URL making the page refresh? Also, you should always show your code so you can get quicker assistance and so it doesn't look like you just want someone to do the task for you.

Comment: Well, if you can use ajax to get the new messages, what stops you using the same technique to post the form content? Just add an `event.preventDefault` in the submit event handler and do the posting yourself with ajax. But there are many other approaches. Actually, you don't need a form at all. But, unless this is just an assignment for you, this technique is outdated for such tasks. You should consider real-time support instead: https://entwickler.de/webandphp/building-realtime-web-apps-with-php-125787.html

Answer (score -1):

Submit your form with a button that is not an input of type submit and call a javascript function in the onclick event that makes an ajax call. That will prevent the page from refreshing.

Comment: I'd rather listen for _submit_ events on the `<form>` than _click_ events on a button. That way you can catch hitting `Enter` in a text field as well